# What does vc mean in rails and is there any documentation for it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project alongside a senior dev and he uses this ruby code often:

```
  <%= vc 'progress_step', (params) %>
```

I can see from investigating this is rendering a component by the name of progress_step (go figure). Therefore I can only presume vc is abbreviated from 'view component' maybe? My question is less what is it doing and more where is the documentation for this if this is a pre-defined helper?

He is using it for many different components for the pages. It seems really useful so I'd like to learn more.

UPDATE: This is a custom method the developer has defined in the project to generate template components like radio buttons and modals so they look consistent by passing the parameters to the helper.

Comment: This must be some custom method

Comment: Agreed, I have since found the method in a helper file. Didn't look hard enough the first time round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since found out this is indeed a custom helper method rendering a component based off of the parameters that are passed in.